# SVG generation by Visio

Tags: svg, visio

I am using Visio to graphically edit shapes for my game, export SVG from it and then parse the SVG. When a shape is rotated, the transform attribute is like this

transform="translate(273.238,7.61209) rotate(-45)"

Here, the shape is being rotated about the origin and this necessitates the change in translate coordinates. However, for my game, I need Visio to use the optional cx and cy parameters for rotate and send the shape's center as the origin about which to rotate the shape. This will give me the correct translation coordinates that I require.

How to make Visio do this? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot let visio to do this.

You have to write a program to convert the transform attribute after exporting.